# Chesscademy Tactic

Tags: tactics, puzzles

Why would black move their knight (b8) to d7 vs taking the bishop (f5) with the queen? Click the link to see an interactive version, can someone explain this to me, I see no reason for black to lose their queen?

[image: board]

[Source](https://www.chesscademy.com/tactics/10326)

Comment: The answer is provided by the tag "mate theat."  The explanation should say "Bxf5" instead of "Bxg6."

Answer (score 1):

If Black takes the bishop on `f5` then White plays `Qd8` with checkmate.

Black plays `Nd7` in order to prevent checkmate.